# Do we have any experts on "applications"?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

The [applications](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/applications) tag has suddenly been added to a lot of posts by an enthusiastic tagger.  There are now over 400 questions.  I didn't do an exhaustive review of these, but for the ones I looked at, this tag doesn't add anything useful (and I can't imagine how it might).

Perhaps if we start deleting it question by question, we'll discover a few cases where it either adds something or could be replaced by something more meaningful.  My suggestion is to either start that process or just nuke it from 30,000 feet and save flooding the active questions list.

Comment: No tag badges affected, I'd say

Answer (score 45):

This is clearly a meta tag – no reason to have it really. This is Super User, a site for questions about computer hardware and software. Applications are software, so the tag really makes no more sense than [software](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/software) which is of course blacklisted.

The user in question has been notified that these types of edits are counterproductive. If you see these types of edits continue to occur, please flag the posts which have been edited for moderator attention.

As for the posts which have already been edited... I see no use in keeping [application](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/application) around personally. If nobody disagrees, we can go ahead and just burninate the tag, but I'll wait to get some comments before going ahead with that.

Comment: Upon further inspection, there are some questions tagged [tag:applications] which should perhaps be tagged [tag:windows-store-app]. Does anybody want to go through and look for those before we burninate the tag?

Comment: These two search queries should get most of 'em: https://superuser.com/search?q=%5Bapplications%5D+windows+8, https://superuser.com/search?q=%5Bapplications%5D+windows+10

Comment: How do you go about re-tagging them? Simply edit all the questions, remove [tag:applications] and add [tag:windows-store-app]?

Comment: @Insane aye. Any question where it looks like being an "application" is actually relevant should be retagged to a more specific tag, i.e. windows-store-app.

Comment: Right I just didn't know if this is something that is done via a mod tool or if anyone with the time can go through and make the edits to the tags.

Comment: @Insane anybody can do it. If we were mass-changing _all_ instances of a tag to something else there's a mod tool for that, but unfortunately there's no bulk conditional retag tool. Once any useful instances are edited then we do have a tool to just remove all instances of the tag.

Comment: Well, here goes nothing. Thanks for the info :)